# Cleaning Tomcat server causes 500 error

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I had a Servlet that was running fine.  Due to some weird errors I was exploring the space (new to this Servlet area) and chose to 'clean' the server (not the project).  After doing so I am getting the following error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Wrapper cannot find servlet class MyServ or a class it depends on

I've seen where others get this error as the Servlet does not have a package defined, but this Servlet was working and I never changed the servlet code.

What did the clean do that may have contributed to this?  I am using Eclipse Kepler to run this environment.

[image]

Stack trace:

```
Apr 24, 2014 7:14:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet MyServ
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyServ
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Serv</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>MyServ</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyServ</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyServ</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServ</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServ</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServ</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Logs/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServ</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Analyzer/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Picture showing how build is not an option
[image]

Comment: Maybe MyServ was a JSP, was compiled at first hit into temporary area and then the JSP source was gone ?

Comment: What do you mean by "clean"?

Comment: In eclipse, 'Servers' tab, right-click on server, select 'Clean...' from the menu.

Comment: @PeterMmm - what does that mean?  Sorry, VERY new to Servlets...

Comment: Did you run "Build" again after doing the "Clean"?

Comment: There is no 'build' option for the Server.  Attached photo shows option.  Under Project...  The build option is not highlighted (cannot select)

Comment: Can you please post the entire stack trace here in addition to the web.xml, servlet class. Please make sure that the classes folder is lowercase like myservlet/WEB-INF/classes

Comment: I do not have a myservlet/WEB-INF/classes folder.  There is a WEB-INF folder, but no classes folder under that.  This folder was not there when this was working either.

Comment: @WildBill: That is the reason JVM is throwing ClassNotFoundException as there is no MyServ class under WEB-INF. Please try building the project again.

Comment: How do I add classes to that folder?  Do I need to create a 'classes' folder, then add classes to that folder?  Or copy the Servlet class to that folder?  Can I just drag and drop?

Comment: @WildBill: Try building the project

Comment: I cannot build.  Build is greyed out on the menu.

Comment: Try to export as war file to webapps directory and check whether you are able to get all the file in application. Then, delete the server from eclipse, close the eclipse and open it, refresh. add the server again and try to run the application with the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete the old servlet and build a new one from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

JVM is throwing ClassNotFoundException as there is no MyServ class under WEB-INF present within the project. Refactor the servlet by moving the Servlet Java class within a package and include the fully qualified class under web.xml belonging to the project & not tomcat. Servlet class inside web.xml should be:

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>MyServ</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>packagename.MyServ</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

[image: Here is where you specify the package in Eclipse]

Comment: What does this mean?  How do I do this within Eclipse?

Comment: I tried moving the class to the folder but Eclipse will not let me do that

Comment: Also I noticed there are two web.xml files.  One under the tomcat server and one under the package.  To which one are you referring?

Comment: the package name is (default package).  How can I place that in the xml?  Also, which web.xml file are you referring to?  Also, the package name was not in there earlier prior to the 'Clean'.  What did this clean do?  This is NOT the project clean but the tomcat clean.

Comment: @WildBill: Create a new package and move the class in that package. Am referring to the project's web.xml which is different than the tomcat's web.xml. Tomcat clean did not do anything to the package.

Comment: Wait, you show a picture creating a new servlet.  Should I create a new servlet or move the existing one?

Comment: Can you please repost your servlet class, web.xml and the stack trace. Please make sure to build the project in case the build option is not greyed out in project. Please start from scratch by copying your existing servlet to a text editor(notepad), deleting it and re-creating the same.

Comment: I'd rather not re-create everything.  It took me a couple of days to add the other supporting classes to this project, add the other supporting jar files and get it all working.  Everything worked great until I did a 'clean' on the Apache server.  Once I did that I got the 500 error.  I still do not know what that did.  Do you know what that does to a configuration?

Comment: Clean purges all webapps and redeploys them, try restarting the tomcat to see if that helps.

Comment: How does the clean 're-deploy'?

Comment: Performing Clean when tomcat instance is running will result in losing all the compiled JSPs and other stuff however when a JSP gets recompiled when called.

Comment: If it helps, this is the extent of my knowledge of how to use/run a web app on tomcat while using Eclipse:  http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/servlet/how-to-create-a-servlet-with-eclipse-and-tomcat/

Comment: Create a new package & refactor --> Move or drag and drop the servlet to that package.

Comment: A new package withing that 'Dynamic Web Application'?  I made a new package under that project already and that did not work

Comment: Once you made the changes, can you please repost web.xml and the stack trace

Comment: I'm not sure what changes to make.  I created a new package within that project but the stack trace is the same...

Comment: I ended up having to rebuild everything.  That worked.  IT took me an hour or so to re-set up the entire environment and start from scratch.  Despite doing everything you suggested, this was the only thing that worked :(

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to note here:

- It is a very bad practice to have your classes including your servlets in default package. Try to add your servlet (MyServ) in a proper package.
- The error indicate that the servlet can not be found. Did you compile after clean. You can make some changes in your servlet to force the compilation.
- You can also stop server, clean project and refresh.

Comment: I do not think I have my classes including my servlet.  I have two packages, one for the servlet, one for another package I am referencing.  They are all in a project within eclipse.  I have done a clean and re-compile but I am still getting the errors.  I've also stopped Tomcat, cleaned and refreshed.  No dice.

Comment: What I meant was that your servlet is in a default package **<servlet-class>MyServ</servlet-class>**. What is the package?